# vbs get timezone string mapped to englisch

Tags: vbscript

I try to get the timezone from the Win32_TimeZone object at a vbs script.
But the Win32_TimeZone Caption returns a translated string dependent of the default system language.
Is it possible to get the englisch mapped value from Win32_TimeZone.Caption?

Answer (score 0):

No.  The Time and Date settings are regional and dependent upon the locale of the local computer.  You would need to compile a list of each time zone for yourself (as an array or dictionary) and then reference the Bias property.

Comment: You are welcome.  If you found this answer helpful, please remember to mark you question answered.